# Unable to assign global variables from functions inside of kivy class

Tags: python-3.x

```
def callback1(self, instance):
    global day = self.user1.text
    global day_type = self.user2.text
    global split = self.user3.text
    current_day = ExcelEdit.split_def_start(day, day_type)
    Workout_app.screen_manager.current = "Input"
```

#The error is (global day = self.user1.text) SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
#I have all three variables defined outside of the class yet I am unable to update them

Comment: you need to provide an [mre] otherwise we cannot help you properly with this

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning these values to the variables and then creating a global variable on the same line, which doesn't seem to be valid Python syntax. You will have to write it as:

```
global day
global day_type
global split
day = self.user1.text
day_type = self.user2.text
split = self.user3.text
```

Answer (score 0):

The hint is in invalid syntax.
You cannot say `global <var> = <val>` you have to "define" the global variable in one line and then assign to it in the next.

Here is a tiny working example of how it should look

```py
day = 1
day_type = 2
split = 4
class Test:

    def callback1(self):
        global day
        global day_type
        global split
        
        day = 10
        day_type = 20
        split = 3



if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Day: {}".format(day))
    print("Day Type: {}".format(day_type))
    print("Split: {}".format(split))
    
    a = Test()
    a.callback1()

    print("")
    print("")
    print("Day: {}".format(day))
    print("Day Type: {}".format(day_type))
    print("Split: {}".format(split))
```

Thereby your code should look like this:

```py
def callback1(self, instance):
    global day 
    global day_type
    global split

    day = self.user1.text
    day_type = self.user2.text
    split = self.user3.text

    current_day = ExcelEdit.split_def_start(day, day_type)
    Workout_app.screen_manager.current = "Input"
```